# How to pause javascript execution during rollover?

Tags: javascript, debugging, webkit

I'm looking for a way to capture HTML of objects that are rendered on rollover. An example would be:

1. Mouse over object to get popup
2. Press button or key to pause js (to prevent mouse out trigger)
3. Right click and inspect element to get HTML

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, `<object onmouseover="functionPopup();" onmouseout="functionWrap();">`

then place your onkeyup-event to detect the button/key.

The trick is to leave the functionWrap on the object ALONE!!! and OVERWRITE this function functionWrap() (that is referenced by object's onmouseout) with the updated instructions (this works pretty good crossbrowser -even older ones-, since this uses the traditional event model :P ).

Happy tweaking!!

Comment: I like this idea... It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it is the least intrusive. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. When I figured this out it made me grin to ;) As a bonus this is also pretty efficient in preventing IE's well-known event-handler memory-leak.

Answer (score 1):

To your main question, there are two ways to pause the execution of a Javascript thread:

1. Hit a breakpoint in a debugger
2. Insert an `alert()` into the javascript thread and when it fires, it will suspend the execution of that javascript thread until the alert dialog is dismissed.

You haven't described the environment you're operating in and what types of modifications you can or can't make to the host page for us to advise more specifically.

To approach the problem differently, to capture some dynamically inserted HTML there are other strategies.  For example, you can use your own javascript (like a bookmarklet) to attach an event handler to the mouse over.  You can then set a timer that will watch for when the dynamically generated HTML seems to be present and grab a copy of it.  Keep in mind that javascript is single threaded so your own timer will only run when the other javascript thread is waiting for user input, but if the general model is that it pops something up on mouseover and then waits for additional mouse events, then this could work.

Comment: #1 doesn't work because I'm looking to do this without diving into js. The idea is that I can leave the js code alone and perform this on the browser side (this prevents me from having to modify the code for each project; at that point, I would simply remove the mouseover handler)

Comment: #2 doesn't work because the alert popup prevents accessing the underlying HTML. When it is present, I cannot right click and inspect HTML on the page.

Comment: @Sebastian - I answered the question you asked (how to pause javascript).  Maybe next time you could pick a title that is more about the actual problem you're trying to solve because it looks like that is more what you were actually interested in answers for.

Comment: Based on my question, in particular the ordered list, your answer did not help me. You did however describe the two ways most developers learn how to pause Javascript within their first debugging tutorial. I described in the comments above the reason your answer did not suffice. If your complaint is that my title did not convey enough information, then I would say that's the reason StackOverflow gives an area called a description for every question. If everyone answered questions in such a literal way, Stack wouldn't be that useful, now would it?

Comment: @Sebastian - I was making a suggestion that you make sure all aspects of your question are asking what you really want an answer to.  It will get you better answers.  In my case, I was misled as to what answer you actually wanted so I wasn't able to help you.  Not only did I waste my time, but you missed a chance at another answer.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I did more than most inquisitors. I not only explained why both your points did not suffice, but also proceeded to thank you. I'm extremely grateful to anyone that takes the time to try and answer a question. I'm not, however, grateful when someone responds and, when not selected, attempts to put the fault on the inquisitor. You didn't read the question's description. If you did, you would have realized that what you offered wasn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: @Sebastian - Your title and your point #2 in the question description both ask how to pause javascript. Never mind - I thought I was helping you write clearer questions next time.  I will stop doing that now.  Bye.